# XStream does not deserialize back from XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xstream

I use `XStream` with `DomDriver` to serialize and deserialize a `DefaultStyledDocument` object, so I save and retrieve it's state in a database. The serialization part goes well, but when it tries to deserialize, an excetption is thrown:

> `[Fatal Error] :92:51: Character reference "&#
>   Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException:  : Character reference "&#`

I believe &# is the space character in the document.

I even tried using a different driver like: `StaxDriver`, `JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver` and `JettisonMappedXmlDriver`, but had no luck.

What am I doing wrong here?

Here's my code:

```
DefaultStyledDocument doc = new DefaultStyledDocument();
//initialize doc
XStream xmlstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
String xml = xmlstream.toXML(doc);
//save 'xml' in database

//select from database
DefaultStyledDocument document = (defaultStyledDocument) xmlstream.fromXML(result.getString(1));
//this is where the exception is thrown.
```

**EDIT**
Actually &# is not a space character, because now i see that the space character is represented by " ". &# seems to be the not edited (empty) part of the document. It's really annoying that is serializes it, but doesn't deserialize it back.

Comment: Can you show an example of the XML?

Comment: Or at least the bit around the error (line 92).

Comment: @IanRoberts <array class="char-array">www.google.com &#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;&#x0;... and this goes on for quite a bit, and then there are standard closing tags.

Comment: Then the error message is correct - `&#x0;` is not legal in XML 1.0.  It looks like the serializer is being lenient in allowing this to be written, but the parser is (correctly) rejecting it as malformed at read time.  I would suggest you look at a non-XML solution for this, maybe `ObjectOutputStream` to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and store the resulting bytes as a BLOB.

Comment: @IanRoberts Do you think JSON would work?

Comment: XStream backed by JSON might be worth a try but it depends at what level that is implemented - if it works by translating the JSON data into XML parser events it may fall foul of the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the XML snippet you provided in the comments above, the error message is correct - there are certain characters that are forbidden from appearing in XML 1.0 documents by the spec *even as character references*, and U+0000 is one of these characters.  Thus `&#x0;` is not well-formed XML and the parser is right to reject it.  The serializer is clearly being more lenient in allowing it to be written.

I would suggest you explore other non-XML ways to represent this data in your database, maybe as a BLOB (using Java object serialization) or similar.

Comment: Thankx, you are right and your suggestion works. Here's an example: http://www.easywayserver.com/blog/how-to-serializable-object-in-java-2/